# Tensorflow Metagraph Fundamentals

Tags: tensorflow

I want to train my Tensorflow model, freeze a snapshot, and then run it in feed-forward mode (no further training) with new input data. Questions:

1. Are `tf.train.export_meta_graph` and `tf.train.import_meta_graph` the right tools for this?
2. Do I need to include, in `collection_list`, the names of all variables that I want included in the snapshot? (Simplest for me would be to include everything.)
3. The Tensorflow docs say: "*If no `collection_list` is specified, all collections in the model will be exported*." Does that mean that if I specify no variables in `collection_list` then all **variables** in the model are exported because they are in the default collection?
4. The Tensorflow docs say: "*In order for a Python object to be serialized to and from MetaGraphDef, the Python class must implement to_proto() and from_proto() methods, and register them with the system using register_proto_function.*" Does that mean that `to_proto()` and `from_proto()` must be added only to classes that I have defined and want exported? If I am using only standard Python data types (int, float, list, dict) then is this irrelevant?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A bit late but I'll still try to answer.

> 1. Are `tf.train.export_meta_graph` and `tf.train.import_meta_graph` the right tools for this?

I would say so. Note that `tf.train.export_meta_graph` is called for you implicitly when you save a model via `tf.train.Saver`. The gist is:

```
# create the model
...
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ...
    # save graph and variables
    # if you are using global_step, the saver will automatically keep the n=5 latest checkpoints
    saver.save(sess, save_path, global_step)
```

Then to restore:

```
save_path = ...
latest_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(save_path)
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(latest_checkpoint + '.meta')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, latest_checkpoint)
```

Note that instead of calling `tf.train.import_meta_graph` you could also call the original piece of code that you used to create the model in the first place. However, I think it is more elegant to use `import_meta_graph` as this way you can also restore your model even if you don't have access to the code that created it.

---

> 2. Do I need to include, in `collection_list`, the names of all variables that I want included in the snapshot? (Simplest for me would be to include everything.)

No. However the question is a bit confusing: The `collection_list` in `export_meta_graph` is not meant to be a list of variables, but of collections (i.e. list of string keys).

Collections are quite handy, e.g. all trainable variables are automatically included in the collection `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` which you can get by calling:

```
tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
```

or

```
tf.trainable_variables()  # defaults to the default graph
```

If after restoration you need access to other intermediary results than your trainable variables, I find it quite convenient to put those into a custom collection, like this:

```
...
input_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[64, 64])
....
tf.add_to_collection('my_custom_collection', input_)
```

This collection is automatically stored (unless you specifically specify not to by omitting the name of this collection in the `collection_list` argument to `export_meta_graph`). So you can simply retrieve the `input_` placeholder after restoration as follows:

```
...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, latest_checkpoint)
    input_ = tf.get_collection_ref('my_custom_collection')[0]
```

---

> 3. The Tensorflow docs say: "*If no `collection_list` is specified, all collections in the model will be exported.*" Does that mean that if I specify no variables in `collection_list` then all **variables** in the model are exported because they are in the default collection?

Yes. Again note the subtle detail that the `collection_list` is a list of collections not variables. In fact, if you only want certain variables to be saved, you can specify those when you construct the `tf.train.Saver` object. From the documentation of the `tf.train.Saver.__init__`:

```
 """Creates a `Saver`.

    The constructor adds ops to save and restore variables.

    `var_list` specifies the variables that will be saved and restored. It can
    be passed as a `dict` or a list:

    * A `dict` of names to variables: The keys are the names that will be
      used to save or restore the variables in the checkpoint files.
    * A list of variables: The variables will be keyed with their op name in
      the checkpoint files.
```

---

> 4. The Tensorflow docs say: "*In order for a Python object to be serialized to and from MetaGraphDef, the Python class must implement
>      `to_proto()` and `from_proto()` methods, and register them with the system
>      using register_proto_function.*" Does that mean that `to_proto()` and
>      `from_proto()` must be added only to classes that I have defined and
>      want exported? If I am using only standard Python data types (int,
>      float, list, dict) then is this irrelevant?

I have never made use of this feature, but I would say your interpretation is correct.

Comment: They should replace the Tensorflow Save and Restore page with this answer.

Also. "However, I think it is more elegant to use import_meta_graph as this way you can also restore your model even if you don't have access to the code that created it."  Finally some sense!  I don't know why the overpoweringly prevailing viewpoint on this is the opposite...